# Multiple Instance of same Activity for different Intent Object

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two Activities in my app:-
Main Activity:- Shows List of City
CityActivity:- Showing details of selected city.

The problem is :-
If I select a city "NewYork" in MainActivity it takes me to CityActivity and shows NewYork Details.
If Go Back and select "San Francisco" then it takes me to CityActivity and shows San Francisco details.

Now When I press back of phone device It takes me to each of the cityactivities "New York", "San Francisco",... same like the browsers back button does.

I tried multiple option to fix it but it didnt helped me:-
a.) Calling finish() in CityActivity.
b.) Adding android:launchMode= "singleInstance"  in Manifest file.

What I want to achieve here is if the CityActivity with NewYork object is there in memory and I try to select "San Francisco" City, then it should destroy the activity with "New York" Intent Object and create a new activity with "San Francisco" Intent Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set intent flag " no history" when starting city activity

Comment: Tried it, works partially. It does delete the activity from the stack. But what I want is ONLY DELETE IT when an activity is launched with new City object otherwise show the old City object.

Comment: Try to set intent flag to FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Answer (score 0):

in your city details activity add this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 finish();
}
```

that's all

**Edit 2:**
when opening the Details activity call it like this

```
 Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("Name",Name);
 ....
 startActivity(i);
 finish()//add this
```

when back pressing in the details activity do this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 Intent i= new Intent(DetailsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);//starting main activity
 finish();
}
```

Comment: It's not always back pressed that the older activity remains. Sometimes the activity remains coz a notification comes and it takes to the main page. And from there I select another city then CityActivity with both cities is in stack. Any other suggestion you have?